# Why does taking the `sizeof` of an object constructed with a default constructor always result in 1?

Tags: c++

When I write the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct gg
{
   gg() {}
   int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{   
    std::cout << sizeof(gg()) << std::endl;
}
```

the result is `1`.

But when I use a non-default constructor, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

struct gg
{
   gg(int x) {}
   int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{   
    std::cout << sizeof(gg(10)) << std::endl;
}
```

the output is 12.

Since both examples have the same data members in `gg`, I expect them both to result in the same output.

Why did `sizeof(gg())` result in `1`?

Comment: Why not just `sizeof(gg)` if you want to know how big a `gg` object is?

Comment: @rightføld: [No, it is not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6baa7934a576de8c). `gg()` is a type representing a function taking no arguments and returning a `gg`. Have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @remyabel it's a function type, not a function.

Comment: @remyabel As is mine.  We clearly didn't think of the most
vexing parse in the context of a `sizeof` expression.  (It's
interesting that the standard only speaks about this ambiguity
as between "expression-statments and declarations" (§6.8) and
"in the context of a declaration" (§8.2).  Neither of which is
applicable here.  So it's not clear how this should be
interpreted; the fact that the function to pointer conversion
isn't applicable, and that a function declaration itself isn't
legal, would argue that `gg()` cannot be interpreted as a type
in this context.  But it's certainly arguable.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two versions of `sizeof`. One expects a *unary-expression*, and the other expects a parenthesized *type-id*.  The first version leaves its operand unevaluated. The following is perfectly legal and outputs `12`:

```
std::cout << sizeof gg();
```

On the other hand, `sizeof(gg())` is illegal. It's trying to apply `sizeof` to a function type.<sup>1</sup> The second code snippet is legal and has expected behavior.

§5.3.3:

> `1` ... The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression
>   that has function or incomplete type, ...
>
> `3` The `sizeof` operator can be applied to a pointer to a function,
>   but shall not be applied directly to a function.
>
> `4` The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not applied to the operand of `sizeof`.

The first code snippet fails in Clang (<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf1025ec8c55f7f)</kbd>), and is documented as an extension in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith):

> ## 6.23 Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers
>
> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on
>   pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by
>   treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.
>
> **A consequence of this is that sizeof is also allowed on void and on function types, and returns 1.**
>
> The option -Wpointer-arith requests a warning if these extensions are
>   used.

(emphasis mine)

It appears that this extension exists in C++ mode as well, considering that I [receive a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecba688bfbb7a0cf). In order to reject this code, use `-Wpedantic-errors`. For the code snippet which fails, simply use `sizeof(gg)` or `sizeof(gg{})`. The latter and `sizeof gg()` are needless obfuscation and `sizeof gg` is illegal since parentheses are required around the typename.

---

#### Footnote

1. Some are suggesting that this is the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). To strengthen the argument, consider that Clang will reject any function type, `sizeof(int(int, char))`, `sizeof(gg(int, char))`, what have you. On the other hand, `sizeof int(45)` returns `4` and `sizeof gg(45)` (for where `gg` has a converting constructor) returns 12, etc.

Comment: ok, so if a copy constructor can be applied to an expression that has function ? such as i create another class A. can i code like  "A(gg())". :)

Comment: @mihaly: Only classes can have copy constructors, and functions aren't classes. Furthermore, I'd have to check the parsing of `A(gg())` but it too may be subject to the most vexing parse. In new code, prefer `gg{}` to be explicit.